# Count of queryset where foreign key occurs exactly n times

Tags: django, count, foreign-keys, django-queryset

If I have a django model with a foreign key, e.g:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

is there a way for me to get a count of the number of `reporter`s that have exactly n articles on a specific date?  For example, how many reporters have published exactly 2 articles "today"

```
date = timzone.now().date()
articles_on_date = Article.objects.filter(pub_date=date)
# now what can I do?
```

Edit:
Currently I can only figure out how to do it very inneficiently by looping and hitting the database way to many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using conditional expressions:

```
from django.db import models

Reporter.objects.annotate(
    num_of_articles=models.Count(
        models.Case(models.When(article__pub_date=date, then=1), output_field=models.IntegerField())
    )
).filter(num_of_articles=2).count()
```

Comment: This works and is kind of magical.  How does it know to do the reverse look up of article on the reporter here? when you do `article__pub_date`?  Does article become a property of Reporter?  I thought you had to do something like article_set?

Comment: `article_set` is used on the instance of `Reporter`, for example `reporter.article_set.filter(pub_date=date)`. In your case you just use lowercase name of the `Article` model. `article` is not a property, it is only used for lookup when making queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
from django.db.models import Count

Article.objects.filter(pub_date=date).values('reporter').annotate(article_count=Count('id')).filter(article_count=2)
```

This would return a list as below,
`[{'reporter': 1, 'article_count': 2}]`

 The **1** corresponds to `reporter` is the **id of the reporter instance**